# How do I use Code Contracts to have a compile time assert in C#?

Tags: c#, code-contracts, static-assert

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/964064/57428) C# now has "code contracts" that should be usable instead of C++ compile time asserts. Now I have this magic code:

```
IntPtr pointer;
//blahblahblah
pointer = new IntPtr(pointer.ToInt32() + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SomeStruct)));
```

that requires `IntPtr` to be of the same size as `Int32`. So I want a compile time assert for that - something like this C++ code

```
static_assert(sizeof(IntPtr)==sizeof(Int32))
```

So I tried the following:

```
System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Assert(false); //just to test it
pointer = new IntPtr(pointer.ToInt32() + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SomeStruct)));
```

I pass `false` into `Assert()` so that it surely fails, but the compilation passes just fine.

So how do I use code contracts to have a compile time assert?

Comment: It's still not properly folded into C# - despite the `Contracts` classes being in `mscorlib`, you still have to separately install and then enable contract checking. There's no sign of the support being baked into VS2013, and the add-ins haven't been updated for it.

Comment: By the way, the [Code Contracts extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1ec7db13-3363-46c9-851f-1ce455f66970?SRC=VSIDE) was updated last week to support VS2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because code contracts are not the same as compile time asserts. They are still runtime code but they also come with a static analysis rule set that you can enable in your projects to do what you are looking for.

Take a look at this question which looks like it already answers this issue very well: [Contract.Assert do not throw compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099704/contract-assert-do-not-throw-compilation-error)